# Can an Excel workbook's sheet tabs be sorted within the workbook by VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, excel

In building an Excel workbook with VB.Net, is it possible to sort all the worksheet tabs into a particular order?  I'm building a workbook with individual sheets named by drive letter, i.e., "C Drive", "D Drive", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to improve your Google-foo ;-) Here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812386/en-us

is an example for sorting sheets from MSDN in Excel-VBA. Should be very simple to port that to VB.NET.

Comment: xD My Google-foo is generally pretty good, but I was using "VB.Net" in my queries, not "VBA", so that's how I missed it.  Thanks much!

Comment: Actually, I used "excel sort sheets by name".